# Web3 events not working

Tags: solidity, events

As per the web3 doc, I'm using following code to watch the events from a contract:

```
contractInstance.eNonIssueDeposits({}, {fromBlock: 0, toBlock: 'latest'}, (error, result) => {
    if (!error) {
        console.log(result);
    } else {
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```

The [Tx](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0xa3900cc6dc1f1646d35c18a5d2c160eb543f4de695686e39c2a4c3d321ec9d21) is successful and also logged an event but the function callback didn't initiated. What's wrong with the code?

Answer (score 5):

For future readers.

Instead of using websocket provider:

```
new Web3(new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider('wss://ropsten.infura.io/ws'));
```

I was using HTTP provider:

```
new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://ropsten.infura.io/FouhRlBDjcMlyh0gT7oL'));
```

For events, you need to use their websocket service and you don't need any API keys for that.

Sample code below:

```
var Web3 = require('web3');
var ROPSTEN_WSS = 'wss://ropsten.infura.io/ws';
var provider = new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider(ROPSTEN_WSS);
var web3 = new Web3(provider);

provider.on('error', e => {
    console.error('WS Infura Error', e);
});

provider.on('end', e => {
    console.log('WS closed');
    console.log('Attempting to reconnect...');
    provider = new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider(ROPSTEN_WSS);
    provider.on('connect', function () {
        console.log('WSS Reconnected');
    });
    web3.setProvider(provider);
});

var myContract = new web3.eth.Contract(ABI, '0x....');
myContract.events.EventName({
    filter: {myIndexedParam: [20,23]},
    fromBlock: 0,
    toBlock: 'latest'
}).on('data', function(event) {
    console.log(event.returnValues);
}).on('error', console.error);
```

Comment: websocket stops firing after a few hours.... why???