# In node.js event is not fired

Tags: solidity, web3js, events

I am using web socket to get event. sending transaction works fine. but event is not fired.

also I referred [Web3 events not working](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/51337/web3-events-not-working)

but it does not work, too.

I used eventemitter also. but it did not work, too. I think there is a problem '.on'. Is there any similar case to me ?

My solidity code is:

```
event MyEvent(...);

function MyFunction(...) public {
   ...
   emit MyEvent(...);
}
```

My node.js code is :

```
const events = require('events');
const WSS = 'ws://localhost:8881';
const provider = new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider(WSS);
const web3 = new Web3(provider);
const eventEmitter = new events.EventEmitter();

myContract.events.MyEvent({
    //filter: {myIndexedParam: [20,23]},
    fromBlock: 0,
    toBlock: 'latest'
});

eventEmitter.on('data', e => {
    console.log(e.returnValues);
});

eventEmitter.on('error', e => {
    console.error(e);
});

// ...
// sending transaction
// ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You are listening on an a wrong emitter. `myContract.events.MyEvent` returns an `EventEmitter` you have to listen to this. Check the documentation here https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#contract-events

You can try this method if what is explained in the documentation is not working.

```js
const event = myContract.allEvents();

event.on('data', e => {
    console.log(e.returnValues);
});

//send transaction here
```

Also your `myContract` variable should hold the contract instance. see [here](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#id1)

Comment: Even I tried your method, but it does not work. I think my code can't get event when it is fired.

Comment: console.log the output of your transaction and check if there is an event property in that object

Comment: myContract holds the exact contract instance. and my code is below:

var event = MyContract.events.allEvents();
event.on('data', e => {
    console.log(e.returnValues);
});

but it does not work yet. is there any necessary setting flag when I start geth to fire event ?

Comment: What is the output of the transaction? The transaction where you call the function that fires the event.

Comment: Ah. I inquired the transaction receipt. contract address is null and there is no data in 'log' attribute. I think I should correct them out first.