# Events using Infura websockets on rinkeby Web3 1.2.1. Returned values aren't valid, did it run Out of Gas?

Tags: web3js, events, infura, websocket

I am trying to do a simple event listener with NodeJS and Web3 using an Infura endpoint. I have the correct project-id

```
const Web3 = require('web3');

let web3 = new Web3(
  // Replace YOUR-PROJECT-ID with a Project ID from your Infura Dashboard
  new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider("wss://rinkeby.infura.io/ws/v3/my-project-id")
);

    var contractABI =[
{
    "constant": true,
    "inputs": [],
    "name": "name",
    "outputs": [
        {
            "internalType": "string",
            "name": "",
            "type": "string"
        }
    ],
    "payable": false,
    "stateMutability": "view",
    "type": "function"
},
{
    "constant": true,
    "inputs": [],
    "name": "TGEcomplete",
    "outputs": [
        {
            "internalType": "bool",
            "name": "",
            "type": "bool"
        }
    ],
    "payable": false,
    "stateMutability": "view",
    "type": "function"
},
{
    "constant": false,
    "inputs": [
        {
            "internalType": "address",
            "name": "spender",
            "type": "address"
        },
        {
            "internalType": "uint256",
            "name": "value",
            "type": "uint256"
        }
    ],
    "name": "approve",
    "outputs": [
        {
            "internalType": "bool",
            "name": "",
            "type": "bool"
        }
    ],
    "payable": false,
    "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
    "type": "function"
},
{
    "constant": false,
    "inputs": [],
    "name": "flipTGE",
    "outputs": [
        {
            "internalType": "bool",
            "name": "",
            "type": "bool"
        }
    ],
    "payable": false,
    "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
    "type": "function"
},
{
    "constant": false,
    "inputs": [
        {
            "internalType": "address",
            "name": "_cryptozContract",
            "type": "address"
        }
    ],
    "name": "setCryptozContract",
    "outputs": [],
    "payable": false,
    "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
    "type": "function"
},
{
    "constant": true,
    "inputs": [],
    "name": "totalSupply",
    "outputs": [
        {
            "internalType": "uint256",
            "name": "",
            "type": "uint256"
        }
    ],
    "payable": false,
    "stateMutability": "view",
    "type": "function"
},
{
    "constant": false,
    "inputs": [
        {
            "internalType": "address",
            "name": "from",
            "type": "address"
        },
        {
            "internalType": "address",
            "name": "to",
            "type": "address"
        },
        {
            "internalType": "uint256",
            "name": "value",
            "type": "uint256"
        }
    ],
    "name": "transferFrom",
    "outputs": [
        {
            "internalType": "bool",
            "name": "",
            "type": "bool"
        }
    ],
    "payable": false,
    "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
    "type": "function"
},
{
    "constant": true,
    "inputs": [],
    "name": "decimals",
    "outputs": [
        {
            "internalType": "uint8",
            "name": "",
            "type": "uint8"
        }
    ],
    "payable": false,
    "stateMutability": "view",
    "type": "function"
},
{
    "constant": false,
    "inputs": [
        {
            "internalType": "address",
            "name": "spender",
            "type": "address"
        },
        {
            "internalType": "uint256",
            "name": "addedValue",
            "type": "uint256"
        }
    ],
    "name": "increaseAllowance",
    "outputs": [
        {
            "internalType": "bool",
            "name": "",
            "type": "bool"
        }
    ],
    "payable": false,
    "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
    "type": "function"
},
{
    "constant": false,
    "inputs": [],
    "name": "withdraw",
    "outputs": [],
    "payable": false,
    "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
    "type": "function"
},
{
    "constant": false,
    "inputs": [
        {
            "internalType": "address",
            "name": "_to",
            "type": "address"
        },
        {
            "internalType": "uint256",
            "name": "_amount",
            "type": "uint256"
        }
    ],
    "name": "awardCzxp",
    "outputs": [],
    "payable": false,
    "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
    "type": "function"
},
{
    "constant": true,
    "inputs": [
        {
            "internalType": "address",
            "name": "owner",
            "type": "address"
        }
    ],
    "name": "balanceOf",
    "outputs": [
        {
            "internalType": "uint256",
            "name": "",
            "type": "uint256"
        }
    ],
    "payable": false,
    "stateMutability": "view",
    "type": "function"
},
{
    "constant": false,
    "inputs": [],
    "name": "renounceOwnership",
    "outputs": [],
    "payable": false,
    "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
    "type": "function"
},
{
    "constant": true,
    "inputs": [],
    "name": "isTGE",
    "outputs": [
        {
            "internalType": "bool",
            "name": "",
            "type": "bool"
        }
    ],
    "payable": false,
    "stateMutability": "view",
    "type": "function"
},
{
    "constant": true,
    "inputs": [],
    "name": "owner",
    "outputs": [
        {
            "internalType": "address",
            "name": "",
            "type": "address"
        }
    ],
    "payable": false,
    "stateMutability": "view",
    "type": "function"
},
{
    "constant": true,
    "inputs": [],
    "name": "isOwner",
    "outputs": [
        {
            "internalType": "bool",
            "name": "",
            "type": "bool"
        }
    ],
    "payable": false,
    "stateMutability": "view",
    "type": "function"
},
{
    "constant": true,
    "inputs": [],
    "name": "symbol",
    "outputs": [
        {
            "internalType": "string",
            "name": "",
            "type": "string"
        }
    ],
    "payable": false,
    "stateMutability": "view",
    "type": "function"
},
{
    "constant": false,
    "inputs": [
        {
            "internalType": "address",
            "name": "spender",
            "type": "address"
        },
        {
            "internalType": "uint256",
            "name": "subtractedValue",
            "type": "uint256"
        }
    ],
    "name": "decreaseAllowance",
    "outputs": [
        {
            "internalType": "bool",
            "name": "",
            "type": "bool"
        }
    ],
    "payable": false,
    "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
    "type": "function"
},
{
    "constant": false,
    "inputs": [
        {
            "internalType": "address",
            "name": "to",
            "type": "address"
        },
        {
            "internalType": "uint256",
            "name": "value",
            "type": "uint256"
        }
    ],
    "name": "transfer",
    "outputs": [
        {
            "internalType": "bool",
            "name": "",
            "type": "bool"
        }
    ],
    "payable": false,
    "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
    "type": "function"
},
{
    "constant": false,
    "inputs": [],
    "name": "killSwitch",
    "outputs": [],
    "payable": false,
    "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
    "type": "function"
},
{
    "constant": true,
    "inputs": [],
    "name": "getCrypozContractAddress",
    "outputs": [
        {
            "internalType": "address",
            "name": "",
            "type": "address"
        }
    ],
    "payable": false,
    "stateMutability": "view",
    "type": "function"
},
{
    "constant": true,
    "inputs": [
        {
            "internalType": "address",
            "name": "_beneficiary",
            "type": "address"
        }
    ],
    "name": "getUserContribution",
    "outputs": [
        {
            "internalType": "uint256",
            "name": "",
            "type": "uint256"
        }
    ],
    "payable": false,
    "stateMutability": "view",
    "type": "function"
},
{
    "constant": true,
    "inputs": [
        {
            "internalType": "uint256",
            "name": "",
            "type": "uint256"
        }
    ],
    "name": "lockedWallets",
    "outputs": [
        {
            "internalType": "address",
            "name": "",
            "type": "address"
        }
    ],
    "payable": false,
    "stateMutability": "view",
    "type": "function"
},
{
    "constant": true,
    "inputs": [
        {
            "internalType": "address",
            "name": "owner",
            "type": "address"
        },
        {
            "internalType": "address",
            "name": "spender",
            "type": "address"
        }
    ],
    "name": "allowance",
    "outputs": [
        {
            "internalType": "uint256",
            "name": "",
            "type": "uint256"
        }
    ],
    "payable": false,
    "stateMutability": "view",
    "type": "function"
},
{
    "constant": false,
    "inputs": [
        {
            "internalType": "address",
            "name": "newOwner",
            "type": "address"
        }
    ],
    "name": "transferOwnership",
    "outputs": [],
    "payable": false,
    "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
    "type": "function"
},
{
    "payable": true,
    "stateMutability": "payable",
    "type": "fallback"
},
{
    "anonymous": false,
    "inputs": [
        {
            "indexed": true,
            "internalType": "address",
            "name": "from",
            "type": "address"
        },
        {
            "indexed": true,
            "internalType": "address",
            "name": "to",
            "type": "address"
        },
        {
            "indexed": false,
            "internalType": "uint256",
            "name": "value",
            "type": "uint256"
        }
    ],
    "name": "Transfer",
    "type": "event"
},
{
    "anonymous": false,
    "inputs": [
        {
            "indexed": true,
            "internalType": "address",
            "name": "owner",
            "type": "address"
        },
        {
            "indexed": true,
            "internalType": "address",
            "name": "spender",
            "type": "address"
        },
        {
            "indexed": false,
            "internalType": "uint256",
            "name": "value",
            "type": "uint256"
        }
    ],
    "name": "Approval",
    "type": "event"
},
{
    "anonymous": false,
    "inputs": [
        {
            "indexed": true,
            "internalType": "address",
            "name": "previousOwner",
            "type": "address"
        },
        {
            "indexed": true,
            "internalType": "address",
            "name": "newOwner",
            "type": "address"
        }
    ],
    "name": "OwnershipTransferred",
    "type": "event"
}
];

var contractAddress ="0x8ac7194dbec7250f13b2b76f9fc0df2273f68a56";

const instance = new web3.eth.Contract(contractABI, contractAddress);

instance.events.allEvents(
    "Transfer",
    {
      fromBlock: 5215125,
      toBlock: "latest"
    },
    (errors, events) => {
        console.log('Inside the return')
        if (!errors) {
            console.log('GOT EVENTS!!!', events)
        }else{
          console.log('My ERRORS:', errors)
        }
    }
);
```

I run $ nodejs index.js and it stays open. I can trigger an Event from my dapp and then my code dumps and exits.

this is part of the dump

```
/node_modules/web3-eth-abi/src/index.js:226
        throw new Error('Returned values aren\'t valid, did it run Out of Gas?');
        ^

Error: Returned values aren't valid, did it run Out of Gas?
    at ABICoder.decodeParameters
```

Comment: Try out this answer for event listening: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/71793/53608

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I followed your threads and I still am not sure why I continue to get this error. When i console instance.events I have an output, it seems like everything is configured correctly. Is there anything specific that you think may work ?  thanks !

Comment: whoa super strange. So it turns out my Event is broken or something.. I tried a different action and it worked ! .. soo something is going on in my contracts. Thanks for your help !

Comment: The Event I am testing, works well with Web3 v0.20.7 using metamask in the browser. This new code is nodejs with Web3 v1.2.1, why would it not be able to decode what ethereum is sending back ? my solidity is v0.5.9

Comment: Another update. It works correctly on Ganache with both versions of Web3, so definitely an infura issue ? will start to inquire with Infura community